# Can I create sns color palettes?

Tags: pandas, seaborn

I'm using these seaborn palettes

```
sns.color_palette('light:b')
```

I get from light to blue like this.

[image]

If I go `'dark:b'`, it goes from dark to blue.

Can I go something like this `'dark:b:light`, from dark to blue, from blue to light, to custom every color I use (red, green, blue, purple and other)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seaborn contains a lot of function to create color palettes and color maps.  An introuction can be found at the [palette tutorial](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html) and at [sns.color_palette()](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.color_palette.html)'s documentation.

A way to blend between multiple colors is `sns.color_palette('blend:red,green,blue,purple', as_cmap=True)`.

[image: blend:red,green,blue,purple]

So, the answer to your question is "yes, you can create color palettes". E.g. `sns.color_palette('blend:0.1,blue,0.9', as_cmap=True)` would go from dark over blue to light. (Note that a string with a number between 0 and 1 represents a gray value when interpreted as a color in matplotlib.)

[image: dark over blue to light]